# Sorting Select Option in Javascript - Based on multiple values in same row

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have created a list box like this, and created a title bar which helps to sort data:

```
ID                 Name
------------------------------------------------------------
ID1                Identity One
ID2                Identity Two
ID3                Identity Three
ID4                Identity Four
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a requirement to sort above list based on ID and also on Name, means when user clicks ID, it should sort list based on ID and vice versa. But the problem is from data layer we are getting like this in a single line:

```
ID1 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp:Idenitity One
```

So we are printing the same in options tag, and getting output like above. Code to generate above output is:

```
 <select id="selSort" size="10" style="width:350px" id="rpt">
<option value = "ID1">
        ID1 &nbsp; &nbsp; Identity One
</option>
<option value = "ID2">
        ID2 &nbsp; &nbsp; Identity Two
</option>
<option value = "ID4">
        ID4 &nbsp; &nbsp; Identity Four
</option>
<option value = "ID3">
        ID3 &nbsp; &nbsp; Identity Three
</option>
```

My question is how do I implement sorting facility for above scenario? Yes, I tried to sort, but it is sorting entire list box, not based on single value. At-least now what can I do is format incoming data such way that put all Ids in one array and names in another, so any guide/pointers on this appreciated. Please let me know if I haven't explained clearly

EDIT:

Code I tried to sort a list box

```
function sortSelect(selElem) {
    var tmpAry = new Array();
    for (var i=0;i<selElem.options.length;i++) {
        tmpAry[i] = new Array();
        tmpAry[i][0] = selElem.options[i].text;
        tmpAry[i][1] = selElem.options[i].value;
    }
    tmpAry.sort();
    while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
        selElem.options[0] = null;
    }
    for (var i=0;i<tmpAry.length;i++) {
        var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
        selElem.options[i] = op;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you pls post what you have tried `I tried to sort, but it is sorting entire list box`

Comment: @BalaKrishnan, I posted code

Comment: are you sorting that in button click ? or some custom header click?

Comment: @BalaKrishnan custom header click..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the custom array sort take a look at this [How to sort select base on an id ?](http://jsfiddle.net/fPnjs/1/)

The idea here is just create a arrray and sort that based on its value and than dynamically create the option  based on the sorted value.

Custom sorting code

```
source.sort(function (x, y) {
  if (isAsc) 
     return y.id - x.id;
  else 
    return x.id - y.id;
});
```

Comment: Very thanks for your help, but the thing I forgot to mention is we are not using jQuery... :(

Comment: @PradeepSimha , the sorting part is only in Js, i just used the JQuery to query the elements only. so you can use this.