# Filter name by "Ascending/Descending options in drop down menu."

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, jsp, struts

I want to filter UserNames by Ascending/Descending options in my drop down list, so every time i select an option (ASC/DESC), usernames will sort respectively in that order.

```
<script>

/* xmlhttpRequest send HTTP/HTTPS requests directly to a webServer and load the server    
   response data directly back into the script :) */

    var xmlHttp; 

    function showUser(str){ 

     xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

     if (xmlHttp==null)
     {
        alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
     }

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/Shipping_Order/getcustomer_xml.jsp?order="+str;

     //force a fresh page to load because it's unique, not a page from the cache.
     url = url+"&sid="+Math.random();  

    //the onreadystatechange event is fired ones the request is sent back  
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;

    // sends the request to the server
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);  
        xmlHttp.send();
  } // end of showUser()

  function stateChanged() 
  { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
    {
    var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;

    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML   =                        
                  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("username")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=                               
                  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


    document.getElementById("contact").innerHTML    = 
              xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contact")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
}

 function GetXmlHttpObject(){
  var xmlHttp=null;
  try{
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer
    try{
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }catch (e){
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
  } // end catch outer

 return xmlHttp;
 } // end of GetXmlHttpObject                       
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<form name="myOrderType" action="myOrderType.action">
<select id="order" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option>Select a user name :</option>
    <option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
    <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
</select>
                     <%-- <s:select label="Select an Order"
                       name="order"
                       headerValue="DESC"
                       list="#{'1':'ASC', '2':'DESC'}" 
                    /> --%>
</form>
```

*Below is orderList from controller class*

```
<s:iterator value="orderList">

 <tr>  
  <td><s:property id="username" value="username"/></td>
  <td><s:property id="city" value="city"/></td>
  <td><s:property id="contact" value="contact"/></td>                   
 </tr>          

</s:iterator>
```

*struts.xml*

```
<action name="listUser" class="com.view.OrderProcessingAction" method="listAllUser">
            <result name="success">/adminPanel.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**//View class (Action Class)** 
    //list all users by order ASC/DESC

```
public String listAllUser(){

        this.orderList = orderDaoFactory.listUser();
        System.out.println("execute called");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

**//controller class (DAO Factory)**

```
public List<OrderProcessing> listUser() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<OrderProcessing> orderList = null;

        String order = request.getParameter("order");

        try {

                orderList =(List<OrderProcessing>) session.createQuery("from OrderProcessing ORDER BY username" +order).list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return orderList;
    }
```

**I got my solution now. Thanks buddies. But now an issue to deploy that code in struts2. So new issue is "Calling Action on OnChange event of Drop Down List with Struts2".**

response data directly back into the script :)

```
        var xmlHttp;
        function showUser(str) {
            xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp == null) {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return;
        }

        var url = "http://localhost:8080/Shipping_Order/getcustomer_xml.jsp?order="+str;

        //force a fresh page to load because it's unique, not a page from the cache.
        url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();

        //the onreadystatechange event is fired ones the request is sent back  
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;

        // sends the request to the server
        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }

    function stateChanged() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
             $("#dropdowntable").empty();       
    for(var i=0;i<xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("username").length;i++)
       {

$("#dropdowntable").append('<tr><td id="username"'+i+'>'+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("username")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</td><td id="city"'+i+'>'+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</td> <td id="contact"'+i+'>'+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contact")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</td></tr>');
            /* $("#dropdowntable").append('<td id="city"'+i+'>'+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</td>');
             $("#dropdowntable").append('<td id="contact"'+i+'>'+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("contact")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</td></tr>');
            */
           }
            }
            }
    function GetXmlHttpObject() {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        try {
            // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        return xmlHttp;
    }


//getcustomer_xml.jsp

String order = request.getParameter("order");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select username, contact, city from user ORDER BY username "+order);

while(rs.next())
{

    out.println("<user>");
    out.println("<username>"    +rs.getString(1)+   "</username>");
    out.println("<contact>"     +rs.getInt(2)+      "</contact>");
    out.println("<city>"        +rs.getString(3)+   "</city>");
    out.println("</user>"); 

}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212395/sorting-select-option-in-javascript-based-on-multiple-values-in-same-row

Answer (score 0):

doesn't look anything wrong, except if you are missing to set "str" here

```
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/Shipping_Order/getcustomer_xml.jsp?order="+str;
```

if you set str empty then the result should be in ASC order and str = "DESC" would return results in DESC order

Comment: I am unable to iterate the select options. Code execute once and not showing all users. Might be i'm unable to iterate the all values. Please send me code snippets.

Comment: I got my solution but with Java code in my JSP page. So now struggling with How to call Action class by onChange event of javaScript, drop down select options.

Comment: which Action class do you want to call?

Comment: Action class in struts2 which extends to ActionSupport class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in parsing the server response xml. This is quite old way to make AJAX call. Try using more convenient and robust JS framework like JQuery. Parsing a XML or JSON is much easier there and you will hardly make any mistake.

[jquery ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I parsed the XML responce in HTML by innerHTML. and now problem is it's iterate only once and goes out of control. Unable to loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I said earlier use [jquery ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to http request and [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method iterate the response xml

Comment: Let me explain above snippets. later i deploy this app in jQuery ajax().